# Changing class of h2 inside specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I want to make it so that everytime you click on an 'h2' tag, the 'input' inside gets selected and the 'h2' tag changes background, but if another 'h2' tag is clicked, the current highlight and 'input' selection changes accordingly.

problem is that I have 3 different  that do the same and with my code all the 3 forms are affected rather one. How do i limit my changes to only be contained to that form. Here is some code for clarification
'

```
<form>
    ...
    <h2 onclick="document.getElementById(1001).checked='True'
    $('h2').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    ">
    CONTENT
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="1001" value="1001" />
    </h2>
    ...
 </form>
```

Comment: Are you using `<h2>` tags as a way to get large fonts?

Comment: not really. my h2 tags are defined in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
$("form h2").click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    $("#"+$(this).text().trim()).prop('checked', true);
    form.find('h2').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

All the changes are confined to elements within this form.

Comment: right now the $('h2').removeClass('selected') works perfectly except that it selects every h2 in the document. how can i do it so it only selects only this form's h2's. for example
$('form h2') where form would be the id of that form

Comment: That's what `form.find('h2')` does.

Comment: But that requires you to hard-code the ID, so you can't use this code more generally.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar has answered this from a code perspective.  Let's see about helping pass some knowledge on.  There are some non-code concepts that will help you avoid this problem in the future.

This is a common, and very frustrating, mistake with understanding how JavaScript and HTML work together.  The JavaScript doesn't full "belong" to the h2 element when you put it in the onclick attribute, it just runs when you click it.  The JavaScript can touch anything in the rest of the page.  That's why `$('h2').removeClass()` is selecting every `h2` element.

In general, you should do a few things to help your confusion.

1. Put your JavaScript in script blocks, or better yet separate
   files, not inside HTML elements.
2. Use jQuery to only deal with the
       one `h2` at a time (as Barmar suggested).
3. Do some reading how how jQuery selectors work. [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/) documentation is very good, it will be time well spent.

Comment: 4. Understand jQuery DOM traversal functions, which are useful for selecting elements that are related to the current element.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much. Small modification to your code worked perfectly

'
$("form h2").click(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked',true);
  form.find('h2').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
'